# Real-time SVG viewer

Tags: svg

Can anyone recommend a good viewer for SVG files that:

1. is meant for people who use a text editor to type the markup by hand as opposed to a WYSIWYG point-and-click tool like InkScape
2. allows you to zoom and pan the viewpoint
3. does not mess with your markup like InkScape does
4. preferably can update in real time as you type
5. doesn't need to be a stand-alone tool, but can run in a Web browser for instance

I found this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-viewer/lngkbicefbnocjicnbemapilgglemjgg?hl=en

But it does not allow you to pan or zoom the viewpoint sadly. Otherwise it is ideal.

Comment: SVG is an interactive document presentation format, adding controls to a viewer might collide with the SVG interactivity, so I don't think you'll find much there. That being said most borwsers builting SVG viewer allow zooming with `Ctrl`+ `Mousewheel`, though I don't think they are interactive

Comment: IIRC, the old Adobe SVG Viewer could handle SMIL and JS animations, but still allowed you to move the viewpoint around. But it is no longer supported, and only ever worked in Internet Explorer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Atom](https://atom.io/), [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) plain text editors have a plugin for real time preview of SVG files while being edited.

- [Atom SVG Preview Package](https://atom.io/packages/svg-preview)
- [Brackets SVG Preview](https://github.com/peterflynn/svg-preview)
- [Visual Studio SVG Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cssho.vscode-svgviewer)

Though I suspect they only provide real time preview of chages made through their respective editors.

[image]