# Any Free Live Preview HTML, PHP and CSS Editor like Google WebTools?

Tags: windows, gratis, html, php, css

I am searching for an HTML, PHP and CSS editor that would offer a live preview of the code I write.
I currently use "Inspect Element" to program my website, I first code it in the Inspect Element and then I copy and paste the code to Notepad++ which is kind of annoying and there is another problem: I sometimes accidentally click links and all of the changes I have made are gone!

Is there any actual Live Preview code editor for Windows that is free?

Comment: That is not a WYSIWYG editor, that sounds more like a [live preview](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/real-time-svg-viewer)

Comment: Duarte Farrajorta Ramos, WYSIWYG is What You See is What You Get, which is the same thing as live preview, but it is now commonly referred to as a rich text editor :/.

Comment: It is not the same thing. In a WYSIWYG editor you don't (have to) write code directly, there is no need for a preview, you work directly over the final result. [Bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) is an example of a WYSIWYG HTML editor, rich text editors (like Word or LO Writter) are also mostly WYSIWYG. Live previews explicitly imply a separate preview pane

Comment: Okay, but do you know any of the Live Preview programs?

Comment: Have you seen the link on my first comment?

Comment: That's **SVG** files preview, I am not really sure it supports **HTML, CSS, PHP** live preview.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options:

1. Paid - Adobe Dreamweaver
   [Link to site](https://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html?sdid=KKQTJ&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!110812695883!e!!g!!dream%20weaver&ef_id=Won5MgAAA0Rwgpud:20180428161151:s)
   [image: A]
2. Free - Atom
   [Link to site](https://atom.io)
   [image]
3. Freemium (with paid license key)  - Sublime Text
   [Link to site](https://www.sublimetext.com)
   [image]

There are many more options not listed but these are just a few to look at.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that Sublime Text is not free, from their site: Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use.

Comment: @albert That's a very good point! Thanks for the clarification! I'm changing my answer info right now!

Comment: I tried using Atom, but the HTML Preview package doesn't really seem to work. Do you know any package for it that does the live preview? Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/) is another free (as in beer) and open source text editor with built-in live preview that is worth trying. Unfortunately, Atom (which was my favorite editor up until not too long ago) consumes a whole lot of RAM (~400 MB) on start-up with only a few plugins installed.

Answer (score 1):

Its not free, but is very reasonable.  I use [Webuilder](https://www.webuilderapp.com/).  It is a development environment and helps you writing HTML, CSS and javascript, amongst other things.

It is not WYSIWYG, but it launches the browser for you and shows you what it looks like.  I launch it on my second screen.  I can then change things and press the hotkey to launch another tab.  Or just refresh the browser

It will also let you singlestep through languages such as PHP.   The fee is around $60, one off, no subscriptions.  Note, I am not associated with it, I just use it.

[image]